# Comparing dictionary key values in a list python

Tags: python

I have a list containing a dictionary that includes the same keys with different values.
Is there a way to compare the keys in the list across different dictionaries?

For example;
I have

```
title_must_include = ['some', 'title']
my_list = [{'title':'some title', 'year':2021},{'title':'another title', 'year':2018}]
```

Now I want to kind of go through the list and see which dictionaries contain all works included in the `title_must_include` variable and then compare the years to see which is more recent and return the dictionary that runs true to that condition.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension, `all` method and `max` to get the most recent year

```
title_must_include = ['some', 'title']
my_list = [{'title': 'some title', 'year': 2021},
           {'title': 'another title', 'year': 2018},
           {'title': 'some other title', 'year': 2020}]

filtered_by_title = [i for i in my_list if all(w in i['title'] for w in title_must_include)]
item = max(filtered_by_title, key=lambda i: i['year'])
print(item)  # {'title': 'some title', 'year': 2021}
```